# AttributeError when attempting to import from smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I have tried the following:

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP
```

```
import smtplib.SMTP
```

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP
```

In all cases, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'

Could anyone explain why? Alternatively, how else could I send mail using Python?

Comment: Use `from smtplib import SMTP`

Comment: added code blocks and cleaned grammar up

Comment: How did you install the smtplib dependency?